# How to prove $\frac{\overline{X}-\overline{Y}}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n+\sigma^2/m}} \sim N(0,1) $ follows $N(0,1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

n and m are integers greater than 2, $\sigma^2>0$ are real number.

A math exam and an English exam were held and there were $n$ and $m$ participants for each. The score of each exam follows the normal distribution with the same variance $\sigma^2$.

Scores of the math exam are $X_1,...,X_n$ and of the English exam are $Y_1,...,Y_m$.

$\overline{ X }=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
$\overline{ Y }=\frac{1}{m}\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m Y_i$

Then, how can we prove
$$\frac{\overline{X}-\overline{Y}}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n+\sigma^2/m}} \sim N(0,1) $$

Comment: This follows from properties of normal distribution if $X_i$s and $Y_i$s are independent and they have the same mean.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm sure they are independent but do not know if they have the same mean. Could you show which properties you are talking about?

Comment: If they have different means then your expression would be $$\frac{\overline{X}-\overline{Y}}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n+\sigma^2/m}} \sim N\left(\frac{\mu_X-\mu_Y}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n+\sigma^2/m}},1\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are iid random variabiles $\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ it is easy to verify (e.g. via Moment Generating Function) that

$$\overline{X}-\overline{Y}\sim N(0; \frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma^2}{m})$$

Standardizing this gaussian distribution you prove your claim

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you show me the process of the validation through Moment Generating Function?

Comment: @ohisamadaigaku: it is enough to combine the various properties of MGF. For independent rv $M_{X+Y}(t)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$ and always $M_{aX}(t)=M_X(at)$